# Buy equipment myself or keep going with what i have - What should i do?

Tags: work-environment

### Some Backstory:

I've been working for almost 5 years in a outsourcing company.

I'm kinda stuck in a project for 3 years now.

I hate all the sub projects I've been working on during the years because they are either using very old technologies and I don't get to learn new stuff or We are using new technologies in one of the projects (Angular 8) but I don't like it very much. Also my "team" doesn't really respects any standards unless they "made" them.
Is the same with third party libraries.

By stuck I mean that this is one of the two companies in my current location that I can work on.(This is paying better but still less in comparison with other cities around). I can't relocate in the next 2 years.

I've received offers but all of them required me to move either in another city or country.

### Context:

I've used a low end pc in my first year.

Second year I got a small upgrade from i3 to i5 and from 4gb of ram to 8gb because i was needing it to work on a sub project that required more resources.

After another year, I've started working on and off, mostly when i was sick from home and I was using my home PC but was a bit difficult to maintain the same subprojects(working on multiple projects at the time) in sync.

I decided to get myself a second hand(probably had many owners) early 2015 Mac (because... low on money) and use that for work. It seemed fine at first but realised after 2 weeks that the display was starting to freeze and until the end of the month it was broken completely.

I was kinda bummed because I really wanted a Mac for a long time and that happened. I kept using it like that with an external display for a year.

It started slowing down also at the end of the year, did a clean reinstall but was really slow and i kept bringing up that while i was at the office and my PM told me that another PM wants to get a new Mac ( from the firm ) and i could receive his old one (same model with 16gb of ram) if i wanted.

I was happy that it had a display and i was able to use it without any external stuff.

One year later the inevitable happened and started to die slowly. I get freezes, high temperatures when I'm not doing anything.. frame drops/delay when editing files, runing commands feels like starting a airplane. Scrolling in a editor is laggy most of the time.

I've started to work mostly from home because I realized that i can get more done when I'm not distracted by the other guys in the office and because i'm using my upgraded pc (again) and can actually be productive.

Working from home is nice but I've realized that i'm not doing any movement. 
Started to feel funny after a while and I decided to start going back to the office on an off again and I plan to keep doing that until it becomes a habit.

Each time I'm at the office, I get done like 20% from what i'm doing while i'm at home, mostly because of how slow the Mac is.

I tried to bring it up again with the PM but he just Ignores me or changing the subject which makes me belive that I won't be getting anything, anytime  soon.

I've brought it up during the standups ( with the clients )  that i didn't managed to get too much done in some days because of how slow my laptop is and they had the same attitude as the PM

### TLDR:

Have a old mac from the firm (someone else's trash is another's treasure), that is now on its "death bed".

Implied to the PM and the client that Is very slow and expected them to react.

I don't want to ask because I'm not the type to beg.

I've taken the attitude (for some time now..) of "I'll work on whatever they gave me"

I've saved some money and i'm thinking about buying a new Mac myself (the new version) that i'll be using for both work and personal projects, but mostly work.

What would you do?

Comment: Holly wall of text. Can you cut it, by at least a half?

Comment: How have you asked the PM for new laptop? Is it in person or have you sent them an email?

Comment: Does your company have a BYOD policy? Why not use your computer at home all the time if it is faster?

Comment: What kind of work are you doing that 16gb isn't enough to prevent laggy scrolling? Are you developing and running services on VMs, or running Spark/Hadoop/something else big-data-ish, or editing videos, or what?

Comment: Do you have proper anti-virus, anti-malware, anti-everything installed?

Comment: Do you have hundreds of tabs open in your browser?

Comment: @shoover Do you have proper anti-virus, anti-malware, anti-everything installed - had for a month but was very slow and I've removed it.

Comment: Do you have hundreds of tabs open in your browser? - no. I usually close everything when I'm done. If i'm not i either suspend it or bookmark it and close

Comment: Does your company have a BYOD policy? Why not use your computer at home all the time if it is faster? - well i want to get back to "working from the office"

Comment: How have you asked the PM for new laptop? Is it in person or have you sent them an email? - didn't asked directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to bring it up again with the PM but he just Ignores me or changing the subject which makes me believe that I won't be getting anything, anytime soon.

It's not clear how you've brought this up, but it seems it has been only by speaking.

I suggest you *send an email to your PM*, explaining that the computer you have available for work is performing slow, and that you require a solution to be able to complete the project in time.

Sending an e-mail is better than just asking in words, as it is harder to ignore and it serves as evidence that you have asked for assistance.

In the meantime, if you are more productive at home, consider telling this to your PM or supervisor and ask if you can work from there so you are more productive.

> I've brought it up during the standups ( with the clients ) that i didn't managed to get too much done in some days because of how slow my laptop is and they had the same attitude as the PM

You shouldn't be mentioning this to your clients. They are not responsible for the resources you have or use for the project.

What they ultimately want is the result, and most likely they don't care if you did it on your Mac or in a GameBoy. Your PM or direct supervisor should be the one you should take this to.

Answer (score -6):

Explain to them that your work machine is very slow and crashes a lot, and tell them that you are unproductive because of that.  If they tell you to buy a better machine, tell them to pay for it, because you can't afford it.  In the meantime, just do whatever work you can; if your company needs you to be more productive then you have told them what you need to do that.

However, to be honest, a new computer, even a Mac, is under $2000.  If your personal finances are such that a one-time $2000 expense will break you financially, you have bigger problems to worry about.  You need to either analyze your spending habits and cut some things out of your life that you don't need, or you need to find a better paying job ASAP, and likely both.  This is irrespective of whether or not you should be responsible for buying your own machine for work (you should not and you should work on whatever they give you and if it's not practical to work on then that's their problem not yours).